# Symfony2 : Doctrine Events Listener updates lost when removing linked entity

Tags: symfony, events, doctrine

I made a listener in order to update some fields at each INSERT and UPDATE:

```
public function onFlush(OnFlushEventArgs $eventArgs)
{
    
    $token = $this->container->get('security.context')->getToken();
    $em = $eventArgs->getEntityManager();
    $uow = $em->getUnitOfWork();
    
    // Inserts
    foreach ($uow->getScheduledEntityInsertions() as $entity) {
        if (is_subclass_of($entity, 'Kiwi\Bundle\TrainingBundle\Entity\EntityDated')) {
            
            $entity->setCreated(new \Datetime()); 
            $entity->setCreatedBy($token->getUser()->getUsername());
            $entity->setUpdated(new \Datetime()); 
            $entity->setUpdatedBy($token->getUser()->getUsername()); 
            
            $meta = $em->getClassMetadata(get_class($entity));
            $uow->recomputeSingleEntityChangeSet($meta, $entity);
            
        }
    }
    
    // Updates
    foreach ($uow->getScheduledEntityUpdates() as $entity) {
        if (is_subclass_of($entity, 'Kiwi\Bundle\TrainingBundle\Entity\EntityDated')) {
            
            $entity->setUpdated(new \Datetime()); 
            $entity->setUpdatedBy($token->getUser()->getUsername());
            
            $meta = $em->getClassMetadata(get_class($entity));
            $uow->recomputeSingleEntityChangeSet($meta, $entity); 
            
        }                
    }
    
}
```

I will take in example an entity Question with OneToMany Response.

This works very well in this cases:

- I edit my entity alone
- I edit my entity and I create some linked entities (example: I had
  some responses to an entity question)
- I only delete some linked entities but without editing the main
  entity

The only case which doesn't works is when:

- I edit my entity AND I delete some linked entities (example: I
  change the name of my question AND I delete one response)

**When I do the last case, my linked entity is deleted (response) BUT my main entity (question) is NOT updated.**

Here is my controller, maybe the problem is here:

```
if ($form->isValid()) {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        foreach ($originalResponses as $response) {
            if ($qc->getQuestionClosedResponses()->contains($response) == false) {
                $em->remove($response);
            }
        }
        foreach ($qc->getQuestionClosedResponses() as $response) {
            $response->setQuestionClosed($qc);
            $em->persist($response);
        }
        $em->persist($qc);
        $em->flush();

        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('kiwi_training_questionclosed'));
    }
```

Comment: Getting this sort of thing to work is one of the trickier aspects of D2.  I would not listen for both preFlush and onFlush.  I think it might be complicating things.  Just use onFlush. http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/events.html#onflush And I think you might then need to use $uow->getScheduledCollectionDeletions but I am not sure.  Anyways, get rid of preFlush and see what happens.

Comment: I did what you suggested and it works the same. Thanks because it's simplier but the problem persist.

Comment: I don't quite follow what your foreach loops are doing.  You are certain that the entity is indeed being updated by your form?  All I can suggest is that you study the doctrine extensions bundle (http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/common_extensions.html and https://github.com/Atlantic18/DoctrineExtensions/tree/master/lib/Gedmo/Timestampable) and see where it differs from yours.

Answer (score 0):

The problem went not from the listener but from the controller.
Here is the new controller working :

```
if ($form->isValid()) {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        foreach ($qc->getQuestionClosedResponses() as $response) {
            $response->setQuestionClosed($qc);
            $em->persist($response);
        }
        $em->persist($qc);
        $em->flush();
        foreach ($originalResponses as $response) {
            if ($qc->getQuestionClosedResponses()->contains($response) == false) {
                $em->remove($response);
            }
        }
        $em->persist($qc);
        $em->flush();
        $this->get('session')->getFlashBag()->add('success', 'Votre question fermée a bien été modifiée');

        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('kiwi_training_questionclosed'));
    }
```

I had to make a new persist/flush between delete and edit.